# Live folders on Android 3.x+

Tags: android, android-livefolders

I have an older 2.x Android app that I am finally getting around to testing out on 3.x, and noticed that I can't seem to create a Live Folder for the application on a 3.1 tablet. Is it possible to create live folders for apps on 3.x+ devices, or are they no longer supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are no longer supported. Instead you can create a widget with a ListView inside.

Answer (score 0):

this app brings back livefolders to honeycomb and above

http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=arnodenhond.livefoldershortcut

http://code.google.com/p/livefolder-shortcut/

Answer (score 0):

i used this source code for my project. i think it will also used full for you. http://androidostutor.net/android-live-folder-example/

Comment: Hi, consider improving the answer by copying relevant stuff from the link - the link may become inactive over time and won't help future users.